# Error 404 blog/page/2/

Tags: posts, plugin-development, plugin-wp-pagenavi

Hello i have problem.

I can't view /blog/page/2/ i klick "_posts_link" and error 404 shows me

Blog Page  -> home.php

```
                <?php 
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $currentPage);
                query_posts($args);
                if( have_posts() ): $i = 0;

                    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
```

---

```
                                <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
                                <ul class="uk-pagination uk-background-primary uk-light">
                                    <li><?php next_posts_link('<span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-pagination-previous></span> Stare Posty'); ?></li>
                                    <li class="uk-margin-auto-left"><?php previous_posts_link('Nowe posty <span class="uk-margin-small-left" uk-pagination-next>'); ?></li>
                                </ul>

                                <?php endif;
                                    wp_reset_query();
                                ?>
```

Comment: once you use `query_posts` there is no point in asking about pagination, just never use it ever. In any case the code you should is unlikely to be the reason you get 404

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need to target a taxonomy. You can use the code below:

```
function query_change_function( $query ) {
     $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'query_change_function');
```

You should wrap the `$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );` around with `if ( ! is_admin() && is_home() ) {//the $query->set code}`
 to avoid it changing to 5-posts everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Use this for pagination

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) : 1;
$content_args=array(
         'post_type' => 'post',
         'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
         'paged' => $paged,
         'posts_per_page' => '5',
     );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($content_args);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()): $wp_query->the_post();?>

    //content here

   <?php endwhile;?>
```

Pagination

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) 
),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );?>
```

Comment: A wall of code is not a good answer. Answers should educate to help people avoid repeating the same mistakes, and a wall of code which contains zero comments and no real explanation as to "why" is almost worthless.